# How to make VFS reading file when I want in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb, vfs

I have wrote a proxy in wso2 esb where I used VFS for reading and writing files.Now when I put the file in the transport.vfs.FileURI parameter the VFS listener automatically read the file and continue processing. But I don't want this. I want with my command VFS start reading file and process.But I don't know how should do this. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward configuration for that in VFS. But there is a workaround always. :) In this case, I can think of 2.

1) Have you file in a different place and move to `transport.vfs.FileURI` location whenever you want VFS to process it.

2) Set `transport.vfs.FileNamePattern` (eg.`*\.xml`) and rename the file name (or extention) to match to it whenever you want to process it.